# NoSuch file exception - Spark Standalone cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have two machines named:

1. ubuntu1 - master node
2. ubuntu2 - worker

I am trying to execute the example, so I have a jar name app1.jar.

When I submit the application, send an error.

java.io.NoSuchFileException: /home/ubuntu1/demo/app1.jar

My command line is

```
./spark-submit --master spark://ubuntu1-VirtualBox:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --class br.com.wordCount.App -v --name"App 1" /home/ubuntu1/demo/app1.jar /home/ubuntu1/demo/myfile.txt
```

Why send me this error ? The file is that directory.

Note: The master and the worker are in different machine.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Caso não conheça, existe o [Stackoverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) - claro que aqui tem muito mais gente...

Comment: did you check if the path `/home/ubuntu1/demo/app1.jar` is correct?

Comment: Yes @RameshMaharjan. The situation is: my worker is another machine, and my command line is in the master node. I dont know if it is trying find the same path in worker node.

Comment: try by removing `-v --name"App 1"`

Answer (score 1):

So, I am using --deploy-mode cluster, this is the why the jar is not found in the cluster. I think that there are workes doesnt have the jar, than the solution was put the jar in each node if I want to use cluster deploy mode.